# Grab a decimal between 2 strings regex

Tags: regex

I'm still pretty new to regex and I have this string:

`Client Version: openshift-clients-4.3.0-201910250623-88-g6a937dfe Server Version: 4.3.0 Kubernetes Version: v1.16.2:q`

And I wanted to grab `4.3.0`, which is between `Server Version:`  and `Kubernetes`

I thought I could do something like: `(\d*\.?\d+\.\d)`, which grabs every decimal number that has a length of 3, but I just want it to return a single number.

So I tried `(Server Version: )+(\d*\.?\d+\.\d)` but this gives me 2 capture groups and I want to store the number 4.3.0 in a variable
I'm playing around [here](https://regex101.com/r/TNFC3M/1)

Wanted to use this regex with `grep` or `sed`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/TYEGIw/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an outer capturing group, and repeat the dot and the digits inside the group using another group if you want to use sed.

```
Server Version: (\d+(\.\d+)+) Kubernetes
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DyDlIU/1) | [Sed demo](https://tio.run/##Xcw7D4IwFIbhv3LCwi0tbVEEVuPkaOIimnA5XBJTtAeZ/O81wQHj9iXvl6cqqbcW634EZ38fUE9wRkPDqHMYH6ipH9qJ1UshtuExF0wJmUmhtiJRMUtT1iVlFu@aFuGEZkazCssfjq8KjcYJaS2z5DLhKn868AbCBtgBXIpuPPg3vItg2TX0Cv4dfuj/ijwIokJGnWvtBw)

If you can use `grep -P` you could only get the match.

```
Server Version: \K\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?= Kubernetes)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gxoLCw/1) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##XYy9CoMwGEVf5cPFSknIT2tVKB06uhQKnbL482mEktjEOvXdU3GxdLoXzuHUldchYKMtRNfngGaCBzo/WFOAHdF4PXQTaVbiyYFKyohgPOdMHFkqJMky0qdVLk9th3BHN6PbCqsP5btGZ3BCv5GZU55SUbwi@EDvcARibxD/B1Sp2v3uUii6bLK8808tiUP4Ag)

For example

```
echo "Client Version: openshift-clients-4.3.0-201910250623-88-g6a937dfe Server Version: 4.3.0 Kubernetes Version: v1.16.2:q" | grep -oP 'Server Version: \K\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?= Kubernetes)'
```

Output

```
4.3.0
```

Comment: ...or `(?<=\bServer Version: )\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?= Kubernetes\b)`.